# Wildcard not working in quotes

Tags: shell-script, zsh, quoting, wildcards

The script is supposed to loop over subdirectories and match all the filenames (FLA.*Image.*file.jpg and FLA.*Image.jpg) in subdirectories and process it. It also create output folder inside the subdirectories to store the results. But the script does not recognize the wildcard.

```
#!/bin/zsh

app="myapp" #my app exe location

for f in **/** ; do

    if [ -d $f ]; then
        m=$f/"FLA.*Image.*file.jpg" # match filename to process
        base_o="$f/output"
        if [[ ! $f =~ "output_.*" ]]; then  
            (
            for file in $f/*.jpg ; do
                o="${base_o}_${file:t:r:u}"
                o=${o%-*}
                if [ $f != $o ] && [ $file != $m ] && 
                        [[ ${file:t} =~ "FLA.*Image.jpg" ]]; then
                    echo "*** Processing the folder $f ***" 
                    if [ ! -d $o ]; then mkdir $o; fi
                    $app ${file} ${o} ${m}
                fi
            done
            )
        fi
    fi
done

return 0
```

Comment: Which bit is not working?

Comment: It says file not found. foldername/FLA.*Image.*file.jpg wild card is suppose to expand and find the file FLA2Image1file.jpg

Comment: `**/**` is a bit strange and might better be written as `**/*`; if you are looking for just directories those can be selected for with `**/*(/)` which obviates the need for the is-it-a-directory test.

Comment: Thanks, What about the wildcard not expanding!

Comment: The `.` is not special in globs, so unless the filenames contain literal `.` characters, any `.*` in the glob should probably be replaced with just `*`, as glob ain't regex.

Comment: hi, I tried removing the " and . it seems not to work.

Comment: A glob is not a regexp: in a glob a `*` expands to zero or more characters same as `.*` in regexp.

Comment: @TmN instead of responding in comment, please amend the question.

Comment: What do you mean I'm "not working"?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

`"FLA.*Image.*file.jpg"` means literally  `FLA.*Image.*file.jpg` and will not be expanded by ZSH.

If you remove the `"` and add the parenthesis, like this

```
m=($f/FLA.*Image.*file.jpg)
```

the wildcards should then work.

You have to explicitly surround the glob pattern with parentheses so that `m` is an array, otherwise `m` is a string and globbing is not done.

Comment: Thanks, however, when I remove the ", still the wildcards do not work. It does not expand the file name. The file name is still foldername/FLA.*Image.*file.jpg instead of foldername/FLA2Image1file.jpg

Comment: @TmN Sorry I worte to many sh scripts ofcourse ZSH does not glob by default see my edit.

Answer (score -2):

```
m=($f/FLA.*Image.*file.jpg)
```

removed . and everything works fine

```
m=($f/FLA*Image*file.jpg)
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate ? this script is working perfectly in my linux `m=($f/FLA*Image*file.jpg)`. Thanks